# Google Map search box outside of map, with map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

Hi I've been trying to create a google map with search functionality. For some reason the search box works however the search functionality implement onto my map, I'm unsure why.

I basically want the search box outside the map to update the map, with location set.

```
 function init(){
            var maxZoom = 3;
            var locationZoom = 5;
            var markers = [];
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: maxZoom,
                minZoom: maxZoom,

                center: new google.maps.LatLng(31.631095, -7.954125),

            };

            var mapElement = document.getElementById('google-map');

            var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

            new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
              (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
                  types: ['geocode']
              });

        }
        init();
```

My Html

```
 <div class="row google-search">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <input id="autocomplete" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="google-map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
```

Comment: You need to link the two things together by listening for changes on the AutoComplete - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

Comment: Ah I get it, just been trying to find this documentation